# Problem with use-package and matlab-mode - cannot load

Tags: use-package, matlab

I am trying to use the matlab-mode package with use-package.

in my `init.el`:

```
(use-package matlab-mode
  :ensure t
  :config
  (add-to-list
   'auto-mode-alist
   '("\\.m\\'" . matlab-mode))
  (setq matlab-indent-function t)
  (setq matlab-shell-command "matlab"))
```

This seems to work - the package is downloaded and installed if necessary, the mode is automatically enabled in `.m` files, but everytime I launch Emacs I get the warning `Error (use-package): Cannot load matlab-mode`. Can anybody tell me why this happens?

Comment: Aware that this is an old post, is this still giving out an error? My call for matlab-mode is similar to yours and it works just fine, i.e., calling matlab-mode instead of matlab.

Answer (score 1):

The package name is `matlab-mode` but the `provide`d feature is `matlab`. Have a look at the very end of [that source code file](https://sourceforge.net/p/matlab-emacs/src/ci/master/tree/matlab.el).

According to [`use-package` Manual](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#package-installation) you have to get that right.

So your `use-package` declaration should look like this:

```
(use-package matlab
  :ensure matlab-mode
  :config
  (add-to-list
   'auto-mode-alist
   '("\\.m\\'" . matlab-mode))
  (setq matlab-indent-function t)
  (setq matlab-shell-command "matlab"))
```

Comment: use-package is not a valid command in emacs 25

Comment: use-package on Emacs before version 29, is a package which can be installed via GNU ELPA and MELPA.